# Opening Program with Python on Raspbian?

Tags: python, syntax

I have a Raspberry PI and I want to automatically open a website at boot time.
So I made an auto start config to run a python (v.3.5.3) script on boot.

The python script looks like this:

```
import os    
import subprocess

subprocess.call([/home/pi/Desktop/Shortcut Final.desktop])
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/myscript.py", line 3
    subprocess.call([/home/pi/Desktop/Shortcut Final.desktop])
                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I got my instructions from a guide that used windows file location, so I think the error is that my file location dont start with a directory letter like `C:`, but I dont think `raspbian` use the same system.

I have not found any other guides that explain how to accomplish the same thing in simple terms *(as i only know very basic python coding)*

I have looked into the `open()` command, but it seemed complicated.

Any tips on how to accomplish my goal/solve the error?

After putting the file location in quotes the syntax error disappears and i encounter a new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/myscript.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["/home/pi/Desktop/Shortcut Final.desktop"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 247, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: `subprocess.call(['/home/pi/Desktop/Shortcut Final.desktop'])`. First thing, there is a syntax error, because you didn't `quote` it.

Comment: @LeanDoer127 update the question please, it's hard to read traceback in comments

Comment: Read [how-can-i-run-a-desktop-file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305795/how-can-i-run-a-desktop-file)